# Leitura de vários dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

Estou tentando ler o arquivo de datasets da Anatel, mas la está dividido por estado. Tem como eu ler todos os arquivos da pasta de uma só vez? Eu fiz lendo arquivo por arquivo e juntando todos em um unico.

```
#Importando os datasets do ano de 2016

df_ac2016 = pd.read_csv('dataset/Solicitações Registradas na Anatel (2016-AC).csv', sep=';', encoding='latin-1')
df_al2016 = pd.read_csv('dataset/Solicitações Registradas na Anatel (2016-AL).csv', sep=';',encoding='latin-1')
df_am2016 = pd.read_csv('dataset/Solicitações Registradas na Anatel (2016-AM).csv', sep=';',encoding='latin-1')
df_ap2016 = pd.read_csv('dataset/Solicitações Registradas na Anatel (2016-AP).csv', sep=';',encoding='latin-1')
df_ba2016 = pd.read_csv('dataset/Solicitações Registradas na Anatel (2016-BA).csv', sep=';',encoding='latin-1')
df_ce2016 = pd.read_csv('dataset/Solicitações Registradas na Anatel (2016-CE).csv', sep=';',encoding='latin-1')
df_df2016 = pd.read_csv('dataset/Solicitações Registradas na Anatel (2016-DF).csv', sep=';',encoding='latin-1')
df_es2016 = pd.read_csv('dataset/Solicitações Registradas na Anatel (2016-ES).csv', sep=';',encoding='latin-1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito usando a biblioteca `glob`

```
import glob
arquivos = glob.glob('dataset/*.csv')
# 'arquivos' agora é um array com o nome de todos os .csv existentes na pasta 'dataset'
array_df = []

for x in arquivos:
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(x, sep=';',encoding='latin-1')
    array_df.append(temp_df)
```

Após isso, você pode unir eles da forma que desejar.

### Edição

Para concatenar eles, você pode fazer assim:

```
df = pd.concat(array_df, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Consegui aqui, mas agora vou ver se consigo converter para dataframe. Ele retornou uma list e quando tento passar a conversao ele so converte os indices.

Comment: @RafaelM. Adicionei uma opção para concatenar os dados. Ve se te ajuda

Comment: Usei aqui e funcionou. Eu estava tentando força a conversão antes de concatenar.

Answer (score 1):

Hoje o `pd.read_csv` ainda não tem essa funcionalidade, porém o [Dask](https://dask.org/) que é uma lib baseada em pandas consegue realizar esse processamento, vc pode ler com o Dask e transformar para pandas caso queira.

Uma solução que não resolve seu problema, mas que é mais generalista seria esta abaixo:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

arquivos = [f for f in os.listdir("/diretorio/")]
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, arquivos))
```